# WebRTC add audio from AudioContext to captureStream

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-audio

I have 3 AudioContexts in my document and a canvas that is rendering random things. I'm trying to capture the audio that is playing in the AudioContext and adding it to the canvasStream so the audio + video is being send over webrtc.

Now the code looks like this:

here I create the media streams

```
this.mediaStreams = [];
window.activeAudioContexts.forEach(context=>{

   const gainNode = context.createGain();
   gainNode.gain.value = 1;

   const destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
   gainNode.connect(destination);

   this.mediaStreams.push(destination.stream);

});
```

Here i create the canvasStream and add the audio tracks:

```
const stream = this.targetCanvas.captureStream(30)

this.mediaStreams.forEach((audioStream) ={
    stream.addTrack( audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0] );
});

broadCaster.attachStream(stream);
```

On the receiving client I can see the video and I can see the MediaStream has 3 Audio Tracks, however no audio is being played in the video.

Any ideas where this is going wrong?

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Cheers,

Erik

Comment: After better reading the spec I get what the createMediaStreamDestination, it requires an audio source which can't be an AudioContext but needs to be an audio tag or video tag. Would it still be possible to use something like RecordJS and send the AudioContext audio over as an ArrayBuffer? Or does anyone have better ideas? My goal is to transfer the output of an AudioContext over webrtc while it's also playing over the hosts audio playback device.